# Our emails are always going to gmail recepients spam folder

Tags: gmail, spam-prevention

Everytime we sent a email from our Business email account gmail are marking our emails as spam and emails are always going to recepients spam folder.

- I tried to send email to gmail from webmail email end up again in spam folder
- I checked our ip for blacklists it is not blacklisted.
- I contacted our host support they reviewed the sent headers and all would indicate there isn't an issue with the email from our server. we have proper SPF DKIM records.

Only gmail is marking our emails as spam. Can not figure it out? Could you please help me to prevent our emails from go to spam in gmail? Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: All of the recipients? Some of them? Only gmail ones? Gmail will mark things as spam, when other users have indicated they are spam.....

Comment: Gmail is sensitive to DKIM/SPF records/signatures and you should not send from IPs recognized as dial-up. For those dynamic subscriber networks it is better to relay over your ISPs or other service mail relays (and accept those as senders). It also helps to actually have working reverse dns records for the IP address of your MTA.

Comment: @djsmiley2k As I stated having problem only with gmail.

Comment: @eckes Our system sends a confirmation email from our server when someone books a tour. We have a dedicated IP and our VPS is located in USA. We have valid DKIM/SPF records. 
Our hosting company reviewed the sent headers and all would indicate there isn't an issue with the email from the server. They say would only be their filtering and nothing to do with the server. How to reverse dns records for the IP address of our MTA?

Comment: dkim=pass header.i=@ourdomain.com.au header.s=default header.b=JJbKZZ+V; spf=pass (google.com: domain of admin@ourdomain.com.au designates 209.182.xxx.xxx as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=admin@ourdomain.com.au;
dmarc=pass (p=NONE sp=NONE dis=NONE) header.from=ourdomain.com.au

Answer (score 2):

It's probably the content.  Gmail has heuristics which read your e-mail and look for signs that it's an advertisement.   Their systems also track known domains that use "wardialing" tactics, such as machinegunning down a contact list and sending unsolicited e-mails.  Finally, they have a "voting" system of sorts where if enough users send your e-mail to spam manually, it automatically categorizes it as such (a feature which seems to have come along with their new category layout that sorts your e-mail into tabs).

If you don't want your e-mails flagged as spam by Gmail:

1. Don't send spam.  People typically don't like ads.  In fact, most advertising is useless drek and is just an entire industry asserting its inflated sense of relevance based on bad statistics.  Advertising is like insurance; it's supposed to help people but usually just ends up making prices go up. If it's anything beyond a sale announcement, it just makes people want to throttle someone 99% of the time.
2. Ensure that your e-mail has text indicating both what the person did to subscribe to your list and how to unsubscribe (with a link to do it when possible).
3. Keep other links to a minimum.  Gmail seems to like them more if they are behind an ad image.
4. If it's written in English, it better be proper American or British English.  If it appears broken or badly translated (i.e. "do the needful" is a major pitfall for Indian companies when they try to indicate an instruction, as are overly familiar salutations) then Google's heuristics can flag it as spam, especially if you've got email content in the body suggesting it's an ad.  It's important for businesses to use natives from target countries to do their translating, unless your goal is to end up on one of the websites where people post their spam and laugh at it.
5. Google may be checking your links to make sure the SSL certificates have not expired or are valid for any website you link.
6. There are some countries from which spam is a common problem.  If you are in Pakistan, India, Turkey, China, Russia, or Taiwan, this may affect you.  If the email address for your company ends in something like ".ru" or ".pk", as most common e-mail addresses for any country use ".com" or ".net", there's a very good chance your own e-mail address is sabotaging you.
7. Ensure that your e-mails are either broadcast at once, or sent in smaller bursts with at least 5 seconds between your SMTP posts.

The above are examples of why your provider may not be able to tell you a problem exists; they are processed through Google's analytics and heuristics at runtime and sorted, so no blacklist even needs to exist.

Comment: Thanks for listing the reasons. Our business is in Australia and our Ip is provided by Australian ISP. Our domain extention is com.au and we have a valid SSL certificate. We never send spam our daily smtp relays are not more then 20. it's a plain text no image no link just simple text which we send to our guests. Many of them reporting that they are not receiving our emails and I found out that all the guests who reported that didn't received an email had a gmail address. All the other recepients get the email to their inbox. Be yahoo, hotmail or other business addresses.

Comment: It may be your business name.  Is there another business unit that advertises on behalf of your organization?

Comment: I wish. We would have more bookings if another business was advertising on our behalf. We are a small local business There is no reason our emails to be treated as spam. I tried everything even wrote on gmail community forum no response though. Please also read my reply to @eckes